# What does having brackets wrapped around the instance of constructor mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have found this piece of code that I don't quite understand.

```
var Vehicle = function Vehicle(color) {
  this.constructor;       // function Vehicle()
  this.color = color;
}

(new Vehicle("tan")).color;   // "tan"
```

Why have `(new Vehicle("tan")).color`

Why the extra `()`

I found the code form this blog http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/

Comment: Try what happens when you remove it: `new Vehicle("tan").color;` (it's a trick question).

Comment: I get the same result. :-(

Comment: Yep. So, that tells you that the parenthesis have no influence regarding code execution / operator precedence. They were probably just used to increase readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't do anything. The `new` operator takes precedence over the function call (the `()` part), so it's the same as typing `new Vehicle("tan").color`. However, it does make the code more readable, and I'd recommend using it.

To demonstrate for yourself what's going on here, try playing around with the syntax to see what happens:

```
new Date().getTime()   //1397073088727
(new Date()).getTime() //1397073088727
new (Date()).getTime() //error
new (Date)().getTime() //1397073088727
Date().getTime()       //error
new (Date().getTime()) //error
```